# Hierarchical Bookmark Generation in PDF using iText library

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have data in **ArrayList** like below :

```
static ArrayList<DTONodeDetail> tree;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tree=new ArrayList<DTONodeDetail>();

     //first argument->NodeId
     //second->NodeName
     // third -> ParentNodeId

    tree.add(getDTO(1,"Root",0));
    tree.add(getDTO(239,"Node-1",1));
    tree.add(getDTO(242,"Node-2",239));
    tree.add(getDTO(243,"Node-3",239));
    tree.add(getDTO(244,"Node-4",242));
    tree.add(getDTO(245,"Node-5",243));
    displayTree(tree.get(0));       

}

public static DTONodeDetail getDTO(int nodeId,String nodeName,int parentID)
{
    DTONodeDetail dto=new DTONodeDetail();
    dto.setNodeId(nodeId);
    dto.setNodeDisplayName(nodeName);
    dto.setParentID(parentID);

    return dto;
}
```

I am able to display above data in `tree structure` like below :

```
Root
-----Node-1
------------Node-2
------------------Node-4
------------Node-3
------------------Node-5
```

I have try Using **Chapter** class of itext library but unable to know how can i generate hierarchical bookmark.

My Question is can i create hierarchical bookmark(like above) in pdf using **itext java library**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PDF terminology, bookmarks are referred to as *outlines*. Please take a look at the [CreateOutline](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=139) example from my book to find out how to create an *outline tree* as shown in this PDF: [outline_tree.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter07/outline_tree.pdf)

[image]

We start with the root of the tree:

```
PdfOutline root = writer.getRootOutline();
```

Then we add a branch:

```
PdfOutline movieBookmark = new PdfOutline(root, 
            new PdfDestination(
                PdfDestination.FITH, writer.getVerticalPosition(true)),
            title, true);
```

To this branch, we add a leaf:

```
PdfOutline link = new PdfOutline(movieBookmark,
            new PdfAction(String.format(RESOURCE, movie.getImdb())),
            "link to IMDB");
```

And so on.

The key is to use [`PdfOutline`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfOutline.html) and to pass the parent outline as a parameter when constructing a child outline.

**Update based on comment:**

There's also an example called [BookmarkedTimeTable](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=140) where we create the outline tree in a completely different way:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> outlines = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
outlines.add(map);
```

In this case, `map` is the root object to which we can add branches and leaves. Once we're finished, we add the outline tree to the `PdfStamper` like this:

```
stamper.setOutlines(outlines);
```

Note that `PdfStamper` is the class we need when we manipulate an existing PDF (as opposed to `PdfWriter` which is to be used when we create a PDF from scratch).

**Additional update based on yet another comment:**

To create a hierarchy, you just need to add kids.

First level:

```
HashMap<String, Object> calendar = new HashMap<String, Object>();
calendar.put("Title", "Calendar");
```

Second level:

```
HashMap<String, Object> day = new HashMap<String, Object>();
day.put("Title", "Monday");
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> days = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
days.add(day);
calendar.put("Kids", days);
```

Third level:

```
HashMap<String, Object> hour = new HashMap<String, Object>();
hour.put("Title", "10 AM");
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> hours = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
hours.add(hour);
day.put("Kids", hours);
```

And so on...

Comment: can i do in existing pdf? i mean without creating new pdf i want to add bookmark in existing pdf.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. i am unable to add third level using this. i mean suppose in your example i want to add child to the date.(ex. branch like Calendar->2014-03-02->Monday)

Comment: It's elementary programming @ButaniVijay, I'll update my answer once more.