# Hierarchical Bookmark Generation in PDF using PDFBox library

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

How can I create a hierarchical bookmark for a PDF like this:

```
Root
---Node-1
-------Node-11
-------Node-12
....
---Node-2
-------Node-21
....
```

I have a bidimensional array (I accept any kind of list/set for the example) with node names like this:

```
1
 11,
 12,
 ...
2
 21,
 22,
 23,
 ...
...
```

This question is base on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734490/hierarchical-bookmark-generation-in-pdf-using-itext-library) but I don't know how to do with PDFBox library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a segment from the [CreateBookmarks example](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/1.8/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/CreateBookmarks.java?view=markup&sortby=date), found in the source code download:

```
document = PDDocument.load( args[0] );
if( document.isEncrypted() )
{
    System.err.println( "Error: Cannot add bookmarks to encrypted document." );
    System.exit( 1 );
}
PDDocumentOutline outline =  new PDDocumentOutline();
document.getDocumentCatalog().setDocumentOutline( outline );
PDOutlineItem pagesOutline = new PDOutlineItem();
pagesOutline.setTitle( "All Pages" );
outline.appendChild( pagesOutline );
List pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
for( int i=0; i<pages.size(); i++ )
{
    PDPage page = (PDPage)pages.get( i );
    PDPageFitWidthDestination dest = new PDPageFitWidthDestination();
    dest.setPage( page );
    PDOutlineItem bookmark = new PDOutlineItem();
    bookmark.setDestination( dest );
    bookmark.setTitle( "Page " + (i+1) );
    pagesOutline.appendChild( bookmark );
}
pagesOutline.openNode();
outline.openNode();

document.save( args[1] );
```